# Error: #1932 Cannot access databases in localhost xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

I cannot access any table in phpmyadmin. I get the error below:

```
SELECT MAX(version) FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__tracking` WHERE `db_name` = 
'shiraz'  AND `table_name` = 'ci_sessions'
#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Verify in the folder C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin folder config.ini.php 
If in  /* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */ the code pma exists

Comment: Try to uninstall xampp and reinstall it in your pc , but do back up your files first

Comment: But i cannot export my databases from phpmyadmin it gives the same error.MySQL said: Documentation

#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__export_templates' doesn't exist in engine

Comment: We can find there really exists the table 'pma__tracking' when we expand the phpmyadmin database.
But the system error call on #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine. So just try to remove the old pma__* database first and reconfig them later.1.Remove the wrong tables in xampp's installation path and remove all the files in var/mysql/phpmyadmin/, which are similar like pma__bookmark.frm/pma__bookmark.ibd.2.Reinstall the sql of phpmyadmin, which located in phpmyadmin/sql/, something like 'create_tables.sql', run them with mysql < create_table.sql,etcThen it works.